# Connecting an Azure SQL Database with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio-code, azure-sql-database

I was following this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-code/) and had referred to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01) and [tutorial about firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on connecting Azure SQL Database with Visual Studio Code but I just couldn't find the relevant options in some steps.

Both [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-code/) and [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure) mentioned "Set server firewall" as shown below:
[image]
But I couldn't find "Set server firewall" in my Azure portal. Here is what I see:
[image]

and this is what I see in Firewall:
[image]

And I got stuck while trying to add connection on SQL Tools in Visual Studio Code:
[image], which is Step 5 in [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-code/). Has the Azure portal changed or is it that I missed out any steps?

---

Edit:

I got stuck at Step 6 in [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-code/). Is there an alternative solution?

[image]

Comment: You have to navigate to your [SQL Server resources](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.Sql%2Fservers) first, then you select your server and there you can manage the server firewalls. If you don't see any resources, you first have to create a SQL Server resource and SQL Database.

Comment: Hi @PrebenHuybrechts, is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/sql/ssms/tutorials/connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) what I need? I do have Database service and Username, must I log into SQL Server to do it as shown in this article?

Comment: I think you first need to [create a SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal) Since your screenshot of your portal with recent items, has only your subscription

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts so I'll have to create a SQL database, navigate to SQL Server, before jumping in to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-code/)? Is anything else required?

Comment: Correct, you can also set the firewall rules using [t-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database?view=azure-sqldw-latest#examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Preben Huybrechts for the comment.

Yes, as @Preben Huybrechts said, you must first navigate to the SQL Server resource, then select the server, and then you can manage the server firewall in it. Before that, you must first create a [SQL Server resource](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.Sql%2Fservers) and [SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal).

[image]

For how to set up the firewall, you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database?view=azure-sqldw-latest#examples).

**Update 1**:

You need to install "`SQL Tools`" according to step 4 of the [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-code/).

[image]

**Update 2**:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I want to link to an existing database service created by someone else but I have the database service xxx.database.windows.net; user name and password, do I still need to create a new SQL Server resource? If not, how do I navigate to this existing database service?

Comment: @nilsinelabore  If you already have a SQL Server resource, you don’t need to create it again. After my test, you cannot connect because you did not install "SQL Tools" in VS. You should read step 4 of the document.

Comment: Hi Carl, I managed to get to the second image in your answer, but got stuck in the following step, which returned `Couldn't find any drivers installed yet.` Could you please see edited question? Thank you!

Comment: @nilsinelaboren  Hi, did you install "SQL Tools" in VS according to step 4? There will be some delay when connecting. After my test, it can connect well.

Comment: Thank you! Got the step working, but login still failed...

Comment: @nilsinelabore   I just found out that I have already install the SQL server driver by default when using SQLTOOLS. I don't know if you have not install the driver by default. You try to install the driver, click `search vscode marketplace`> to find the sqlserver driver in the search bar and install, you can also use this method to install the MySQL driver.